# Tomcat- How to check the memory settings currently in use

Tags: tomcat, memory, java

I have set up a Tomcat server using Server 2008 and IIS 7.
How can I tell if the JAVA_OPTS environment variable is actually being used?

I've heard before that the I have to edit the service.bat file in order to make the JAVA_OPTS environment variable be used, but how can I tell if it's successful?

I haven't been able to find out if there is a way to view this in the logs or something else more quantitative.
The only way I could think of to try to test it is to edit the variable and try to tell if there is a difference in performance.
I set the JAVA_OPTS to be the following:

```
-server -Xmx1k -Xms1k-Xmn1k -Xss128k -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 -XX:PermSize=1k -XX:MaxPermSize=1k
```

Also, I found documentation saying to change the following line in service.bat from:

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" --JvmMs 128 --JvmMx 256
```

to:

```
"%EXECUTABLE%" //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions "-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties" %JAVA_OPTS%
```

I got no errors when I ran the command

```
service install ServiceName
```

So far everything seems to be running as fast as it always is before I reinstalled the service with the changed memory settings, making me think that the JAVA_OPTS isn't affecting anything.

Sorry if this is a broad sort of question, but I haven't found a good lead to go off of yet as to what is actually happening in the back end.
Can somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: Instead of futzing with .bat files you should be using the Tomcat7w.exe utility to modify the service settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I found the information I was looking for so I'm going to accept my answer because I'm giving more details,  but +1 to David Levesque for the leads.

I found out that the memory settings I was trying to set were not being used.  In order to change the memory settings I used the tomcat7w in the \bin folder.

Run the following command:

```
tomcat7w //ES//<ServiceName>
```

Then the following should pop up:

[image: Java Service Manager]

Click the Java tab that is underlined and add the arguments in the highlighted areas.

---

In order to check this, I used the jinfo executable (in the \bin folder).
Jinfo prints Java configuration information for a given Java process.
Run this command using the following syntax:

```
jinfo -flags PID-of-Tomcat-executable
```

The following little script saved me some time from having to find out Tomcat's PID every time, so I figured I may as well post it here:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%i in ('=tasklist ^| findstr "tomcat"') do (
    echo Tomcat Executable = %%i
    echo Tomcat Process ID = %%j
    set tomcat_pid=%%j
)
echo %tomcat_pid%
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jinfo -flags %tomcat_pid%
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `jinfo` utility that comes with the JDK to query the VM flags and system properties at runtime.

Comment: Okay, this does seem to be what I'm looking for, however I can't get it to work.  I ran the following command in my batch file: %JAVA_HOME%\bin\jinfo -flag ParallelGCThreads %tomcat_pid% and I get the following message returned: Not enough storage is available to process this command

Comment: This error is most often seen when running Tomcat as a Windows service . Tools like jinfo can't reach the service because of security restrictions. One option is to run Tomcat from the command line. If you want to keep it running as a service, there are ways to do it, but they involve a bit a work. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906620/jstack-and-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command

Comment: You need to run this command as the same user running the java process, so if you have this error: `DebuggerException`, try e.g. `sudo -u tomcat jinfo 2976`